# Como puedo lograr que un h2 se mueva al cambiar el valor de un input

Tags: javascript, css

estoy desarrollando un simulador de decisiones empresariales y tengo un problema:
Hay apartados en el cual los chicos tienen un input para ingresar un valor y luego de este hay un h2 con posición absoluta que indica si es dinero, unidades, porcentaje, etc
El problema es que necesito que este h2 se adapte al largo de el valor del input, para que no se no se posiciones por delante de este...
Probe hacer algo con javascript y funciono, con un event listener input, detecta cuando el valor cambia, le calcula el lenght al value del input y segun este le agrega padding-left
El problema es que mientras mas caracteres agrego en el value, este h2 se aleja demasiado el final del input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const unidades = document.getElementById('unidades');

let padding = `padding-left: ${input.value.length * 90}px`;
unidades.setAttribute('style', padding)

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let padding = `padding-left: ${input.value.length * 100}px`;

  unidades.setAttribute('style', padding)
  // Esta función se ejecutará cada vez que se ingrese un nuevo carácter

});
```

```css
.col-100 {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

.col-100 form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-100 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-weight: 300;
}

.page-title {
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  font-size: 80px !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 100%;
}

h2#unidades {
  bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.box-pagination a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-pagination a.active {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-100">
  <form action="controllers/update_decisiones.php" method="POST">
    <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap page-title">
        <h2>PRODUCCION</h2>
        <h6>ORDEN DE PRODUCCION</h6>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-wrap">
      <div class="d-flex position-relative justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <input id="input" name="produccion" type="number" value="0" size="auto">
        <h2 id="unidades" class="position-absolute">UN.</h2>
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">Produccion para el periodo actual</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a class="active" href="?page=01"></a>
      <a href="?page=02"></a>
      <a href="?page=03"></a>
      <a href="?page=04"></a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Aquí en el ejemplo, en el snippet, como el javascript, también debes agregar el código HTML (y si es posible también CSS) par spider reproducir el problema y ver posible solución

Comment: Hola Alejo, estás aplicando tu modificación, a la propiedad **padding** que es el margen interno del elemento, deberías aplicarlo a la propiedad **width** que es el largo del mismo ;).

Comment: incluir el html

Comment: Ahi les añadí mas info en el snippet asi pueden ejecutarlo, la idea es que el h2 que dice "UN." no se desplace tanto a la derecha cuanto mas caracteres sean ingresados. @cardosource

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz html y js agregado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo de una forma mas general, voy a usar un método de Canvas llamado [measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) que devuelve un objeto con información sobre un texto medido, como su ancho por ejemplo, podemos usar esta información para mover el `<h2>` dependiendo del ancho del texto del input, lo bueno de este método es que es muy flexible ya que no se rompe al cambiar de tipo de fuente o cambiar el tamaño del texto.

Encerrare esta lógica dentro de una función, que se ejecutara la primera vez, y después cada vez que el input cambie:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const unidades = document.getElementById('unidades');
let prevValidValue = input.value;

unidades.style.paddingLeft = `${getTextWidth(input.value)}`

function getTextWidth(inputText) {
  /* validando texto */
  if(/^\d+?\.??\d*?$/gm.test(inputText) || inputText === '') prevValidValue = inputText;
  else {
    input.value = prevValidValue;
    return
  }
  /* obtenemos los datos de la fuente y tamaño del texto del input */
  let inputStyles = `${getComputedStyle(input).fontSize} ${getComputedStyle(input).fontFamily}`
  /* creamos el elemento Canvas y obtenemos su contexto 2d */
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  /* agregamos los datos de la fuente al contexto para poder hacer el calculo del tamaño correctamente */
  context.font = `${inputStyles}`;
  /* calculamos el ancho, lo formateamos y lo devolvemos */
  width = context.measureText(inputText).width + 55; /* este +50 es porque aunque el <h2></h2> se movia bien, siempre quedaba levemente encima de las letras */
  formattedWidth = Math.ceil(width) + "px";
  return formattedWidth
}

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  unidades.style.paddingLeft = `${getTextWidth(e.target.value)}`
});
```

```css
.col-100 {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

.col-100 form {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col-100 p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-weight: 300;
}

.page-title {
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  font-size: 80px !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="text"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  width: 100%;
}

h2#unidades {
  bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.box-pagination a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box-pagination a.active {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-100">
    <form action="controllers/update_decisiones.php" method="POST">
      <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap page-title">
          <h2>PRODUCCION</h2>
          <h6>ORDEN DE PRODUCCION</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="d-flex position-relative justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <input id="input" name="produccion" type="text" value="0" size="auto">
          <h2 id="unidades" class="position-absolute">UN.</h2>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">Produccion para el periodo actual</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box-pagination d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a class="active" href="?page=01"></a>
        <a href="?page=02"></a>
        <a href="?page=03"></a>
        <a href="?page=04"></a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Me he basado en este [articulo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calculate-the-width-of-the-text-in-javascript/) para elaborar esta respuesta.

Comment: impresionante solucion, la voy a implementar, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @AlejoNuñez de nada, ahi arregle un bug donde el h2 no se movía correctamente al intentar escribir un numero decimal. Esto debido a como se comporta el type='number' y su propiedad 'value' así que lo cambie a type='text' y agregue unas pequeñas validaciones.